# Translation from en to it disappear when show data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, translation, rails-i18n

I'm trying to translate datetime frome English to Italian in my app's form using rails-i18n gem.

I created the it.yml file and entered the

```
                  config.i18n.default_locale = :it
```

code in application.rb

In the form the result was great but when I compiled the form and then shown it the translation disappeared!!!

What can I do???

```
appllication.rb
                  class Application < Rails::Application
                   config.time_zone = "Rome"
                   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
                   config.i18n.default_locale = :it

form.html.erb
                  <h2>Riferimenti temporali</h2><br/>
                  <div class="form-field">  
                  <h3> Data di inizio campionamento  </h3><br/>
                   <%= f.date_select :data_inizio, :order => [:month, :year],                    
                                                           :discard_days => true %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-field">  
                  <h3> Data di fine campionamento </h3><br/>
                  <%= f.date_select :data_fine, :order => [:month, :year],  
                                                           :discard_days => true %>
                  </div>
show.html.erb
                  <h2>Riferimenti temporali</h2><br/>
                  <div class="form-field">  
                  <h3> Data di inizio campionamento  </h3><br/>
                  <p>  <%= @modulo2.data_inizio.strftime("%B %Y") %>  </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-field">  
                  <h3> Data di fine campionamento</h3><br/>
                  <p> <%= @modulo2.data_fine.strftime("%B %Y") %> </p>
                  </div>

it.yml
it:
  date:
    abbr_month_names:
    -
    - Gen
    - Feb
    - Mar
    - Apr
    - Mag
    - Giu
    - Lug
    - Ago
    - Set
    - Ott
    - Nov
    - Dic
    month_names:
    -
    - Gennaio
    - Febbraio
    - Marzo
    - Aprile
    - Maggio
    - Giugno
    - Luglio
    - Agosto
    - Settembre
    - Ottobre
    - Novembre
    - Dicembre
```

If you need some other code tell me :)

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: @Iceman I added some code editing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubys `strftime` is not aware of localization, you need to go through the `I18n` API.

Try this instead: `l(@modulo2.data_fine, format: "%B %Y")`

The `l`method is shorthand for `I18n.localize`